# python distplot with color by values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization, seaborn

I wany to create a dist plot (preferably using seaborn) with different colors to different range of values.
I have the vector:

```
[3,1,2,3,5,6,8,0,0,5,7,0,1, 0.2]
```

And I want to create a distplot such that all the parts with range 0 to 1 will be red and all the other will be blue.

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: It is unclear what you want. In your question you write distplot, then in the comments below you write "a regular plot? ". Include a sample figure in the question to avoid confusion and save everyone's time in unnecessarily trying to solve the unknown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is an easy way in seaborn to do this but doing the plot yourself is probably much easier. First you need to get equally sized bins (if you want that) such that the plot looks homogenous (*np.histogram*). Afterwards it's just a single numpy filter on your observations and the plot.

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.array([3,1,2,3,5,6,8,0,0,5,7,0,1, 0.2])
# make equal binning through the range, you can adapt the bin size here
counts, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=10)

# here we do the filtering and split the observations based on your color code
x1 = x[(x <= 1) & (x >= 0)]
x2 = x[~((x <= 1) & (x >= 0))]

# finally, do the plot
f, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(x1, bins=bins, color="tab:red")
ax.hist(x2, bins=bins, color="tab:blue")
ax.set(xlabel="Measurement", ylabel="Counts", title="histogram with 2 colors")
sns.despine()
```

Gives you:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do it with a regular plot?  (Meaning the first point is 3, second is 1, and so on)

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. What is a regular plot and what is a point there?

Comment: Meaning X axis is the index and Y axis is the valus

Comment: Ok, so indepedant from the question above. Yes, in seaborn it's a single line of code if you have your data in a dataframe. The code is sns.scatterplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", hue="time", data=tips), see See https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html for details.

Comment: No this is not scatter plot... this is tsplot but the question is how to add the condition of  all the parts with range 0 to 1 will be red and all the other will be blue.

Comment: You have to decode a "hue" variable, just like in the example above, e.g. x1 = x[(x <= 1) & (x >= 0)].

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a scatter plot. In that case, you can try the following solution. Here you first create a column of colors based on your condition and then assign those colors to the scatter plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0,1, 0.2])
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':data}).reset_index()

df['colors'] = np.where(data<1, 'red', 'blue')
plt.scatter(df['index'], df['data'], c=df['colors'])
```

[image]

**Alternative** would be to plot directly using DataFrame

```
data = np.array([3, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 0, 0, 5, 7, 0,1, 0.2])
df = pd.DataFrame({'data':data}).reset_index()

colors = np.where(data<1, 'red', 'blue')
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='index', y='data',c=colors)
```